# How to write few values in the same cell in R?

Tags: r, for-loop

I need to compare `table1` with 1 row and `table2` with 2 rows.

In row1 both tables contains the same values but they are randomized and row2 in `table2` contains a few different values for the same value in row1.

So I need to write a few values in the same cell.

This code running but it is incorrect because if values in row2 of `table2` are different for the same value in row1 `table1`, it just rewrites it with the last value it founds. But I need both.

```
for (i in 1:nrow(table1)){
  for (a in 1:nrow(table2)){
    if(table1$row1[i] == table2$row1[a]){
      table1$row2[i] <- paste(table2$row2[a], collapse = ", ")
    } 
  }
}
```

---

Data example:

table1 ↓

```
          row1
1  c43bdf23a60
2 164389427682
3  12398826693
4  48492266219
5 150403618359
6 150403618759
```

table2 ↓

```
         row1       row2
1 32ba31ce836   21315839
2 7ccaba4ce5d   50729458
3 c43bdf23a60   32204599
4 f66cc27fd46  198217504
5 c43bdf23a60  852948367
6 c43bdf23a60   81423505
```

---

any help is appreciated...

Comment: but without a decent [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example, your question is un-answerable

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please, try to add some data to make your example reproducible, and also an explicit desired output made from the data posted.

Comment: Can you post sample data? Please edit **the question** with the output of `dput(table1)`. And the same for `table2`.

Comment: it is hard to figure out what you want, but seems that `ifelse` function should give what you want. example : 
`table1$new_row <- ifelse(table1$row1 == table2$row1,paste(table2$row2[a], collapse = ", "),table1$row1)`

Comment: Also, if it is one time job to replace such values you can edit the dataframe manually using `fix() ` function which opens up dataframe in popup window.

Comment: Thanks for answers guys! I've just edited my question by adding a data.frame examples. Hope now the question sounds is more clear.

Comment: The output of `str(data)` has no help for us to read your data. Please `dput(data)` or `head(data)`.

Comment: Got you - edit again. Hope now is clear.

Comment: Do you mean columns instead of rows?

Comment: @Sotos - not really, but it also could work!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First using `lapply` to build a list with matched `table2$row2` results pasted into string

```
lst <- lapply(table1$row1, function(x) c(row1 = x, row2 = paste(table2[table2$row1 == x, ]$row2, collapse=", ")))
```

Converting `list` into a `data.frame`

```
as.data.frame(do.call(rbind, lst))

          row1                          row2
1  c43bdf23a60 32204599, 852948367, 81423505
2 164389427682                              
3  12398826693                              
4  48492266219                              
5 150403618359                              
6 150403618759
```

This is building a new `data.frame` and not merging with `table1` (not clear if needed).

---

Modifying original code to insert pasted values into `table1`

```
for (i in seq_len(nrow(table1))){
  table1$row2[i] <- paste(table2[table2$row1 == table1$row1[i], ]$row2, collapse = ", ")
}
```

Comment: Getting error - "setting levels for factors are different"

Comment: @Richard make sure that your `row1` in both tables is of type `character`, not `factor`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is what you want: First, collect all values from `row2` for unique values in `row1` of `table2`, then merge with `table1`:

```
merge(
  x = table1,
  y = aggregate(row2~row1, data = table2, FUN = paste0, collapse = ","),
  all.x = T,
  sort = F
)
```

Comment: It wouldn't work that way because if i will collect all values from row2 for unique values in row1 of table2 it would not paste all results, but just rewrite existing results in the same cell. Then aggregate is not needed.

Comment: You might have had the same problems here with your input data (factor instead of character). Because using `merge` and `aggregate` makes it robust, hence you need both: `aggregate` groups by `row1` and collapses all `row2`-values together as needed. `merge` finally assures that all values from `table1` occur, even if they don't have a `row2`-value in `table2`.